# Networkx Dataset Creation

Tags: python, networkx

I have data for a directed graph in the form of

```
Node1 Node2
A       B
A       C
C       A
D       A
```

Which means, a directed edge/link between A --> B, A --> C and so on.
I want to create this data into dataset supported by Networkx for modelling in Python. I want keep the file size as minimum as possible. I have edges/links of about 1 Million.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

content = '''\
Node1 Node2
A       B
A       C
C       A
D       A'''

lines = content.splitlines()
G = nx.DiGraph()
for line in lines[1:]: # skip the first (header) line
    a, b = map(str.strip, line.split())
    G.add_edge(a, b)

nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig('/tmp/graph.png')
# plt.show()
```

[image]